# Connecting Django to MongoDB using Djongo Connector throws SSL Handshake exception

Tags: python, django, ssl, pymongo, djongo

I'm trying to connect to MongoDb from my django application, but it throws

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)` Exception.

This is the same exception, that pymongo throws, when I connect to MongoDB., but I can get the connection working by appending `&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` , at the end of my connection uri. Basically, the MongoDb that I'm trying to connect to, has ssl implemented in it, and I don't want to pass certificates to get the connection.

However, in dango, it expects us to pass a dictionary of key-value pairs in the database configuration section of settings.py file.

I tried specifying the same `'SSL':True,'SSL_CERT_REQS':'CERT_NONE'` connection settings from my application, but it keeps on throwing same exception.

Any help, how to configure certificates or just simply bypassing certificate check on client side to make the connection work is highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Is it solved now?

Answer (score 0):

It is limitation of the djongo code under file: '<>\Lib\site-packages\djongo\base.py'

```
    def get_connection_params(self):
    """
    Default method to acquire database connection parameters.

    Sets connection parameters to match settings.py, and sets
    default values to blank fields.
    """
    valid_settings = {
        'NAME': 'name',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': 'port',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'AUTH_SOURCE': 'authSource',
        'AUTH_MECHANISM': 'authMechanism',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': 'enforce_schema',
        'REPLICASET': 'replicaset',
        'SSL': 'ssl',
        'SSL_CERTFILE': 'ssl_certfile',
        'SSL_CA_CERTS': 'ssl_ca_certs',
        'READ_PREFERENCE': 'read_preference'
    }
    connection_params = {
        'name': 'djongo_test',
        'enforce_schema': True
    }
    for setting_name, kwarg in valid_settings.items():
        try:
            setting = self.settings_dict[setting_name]
        except KeyError:
            continue

        if setting or setting is False:
            connection_params[kwarg] = setting

    return connection_params
```

In the above code, valid_settings dictionary should have one more key value pair which is 'SSL_CERT_REQS': 'ssl_cert_reqs'.

Moreover, since ssl.CERT_NONE is 0 (first ordinal in IntEnum), so we need to add one more or condition 'setting == 0' with 'setting or setting is False'

You can manually add this line and it should work thereafter if you add following line in settings's DATABASES' default dictionary:
'SSL_CERT_REQS': ssl.CERT_NONE,

So the final updated method is given below:

```
def get_connection_params(self):
    """
    Default method to acquire database connection parameters.

    Sets connection parameters to match settings.py, and sets
    default values to blank fields.
    """
    valid_settings = {
        'NAME': 'name',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': 'port',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'AUTH_SOURCE': 'authSource',
        'AUTH_MECHANISM': 'authMechanism',
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': 'enforce_schema',
        'REPLICASET': 'replicaset',
        'SSL': 'ssl',
        'SSL_CERTFILE': 'ssl_certfile',
        'SSL_CA_CERTS': 'ssl_ca_certs',
        'READ_PREFERENCE': 'read_preference',
        'SSL_CERT_REQS': 'ssl_cert_reqs'
    }
    connection_params = {
        'name': 'djongo_test',
        'enforce_schema': True
    }
    for setting_name, kwarg in valid_settings.items():
        try:
            setting = self.settings_dict[setting_name]
        except KeyError:
            continue

        if setting or setting is False or setting == 0:
            connection_params[kwarg] = setting

    return connection_params
```